# Can I edit memory usage of Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I have a bunch of emails (dating from 2005, and the advent of Gmail). Most of these emails have an attachment or more. The sum (mails with embedded content, and attachments) storage consumed is around 18 GB at present. These are stored locally into a humonguous MBOX file. Perhaps as a consequence of it's size, Thunderbird takes upto 30min to generate summary & index when first it starts in the morning. The attachments were/are documents of consequence; ergo, they may not be deleted. My colleague has atleast another 20-25 years of professional life to do, so we may well be looking at upto 50GB MBOX sooner or later.

Is there a way to increase the memory allocation to Thunderbird at startup similar to the Xms/Xmx arguments that could be provided to JVM?

Comment: Thunderbird does not use garbage collection like the JVM. Instead, maybe look into simply not having everything in one large file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with Outlook you can create additional fake mail to create mbox structure and then move there archive mails. This will help you keep all the mails in one Thunderbird profile.

Of course you can create second profile and move there the archive mails too.

Here is the procedure (from [here](https://commons.lbl.gov/display/%7Ejwelcher@lbl.gov/Reading+an+mbox+file+with+Thunderbird))

> You need to let it create a Thunderbird account so that you have the
> directory structure to place the mbox file in the right location. The
> easiest way I found to do this is to set it up with a fake gmail
> account, or your own. Just don't give it the password.
> (test@gmail.com?) Then "Create Account" to make the directory
> structure.
>
> (Thunderbird 31)
>
> ```
> Would you like a new email address?
>     unselect "gandi.net"
>     "I think I'll configure my account later"
> Accounts -> Create a new account: 
>     click on "Newsgroups"
> Identity:
>     Your Name: First Last
>     Email Address: username@lbl.gov
> Incoming Server:
>     Newsgroup Server: nntp.lbl.gov
>     Account Name: NEWS-UNUSED
>     DONE
> ```
>
> (Thunderbird 45)
>
> ```
> Would you like a new email address?
>     unselect "gandi.net"
>     "I think I'll configure my account later"
> Accounts -> Create a new account: 
>     click on "Newsgroups"
> Identity:
>     Your Name: First Last
>     Email Address: username@lbl.gov
> Incoming Server:
>     Newsgroup Server: nntp.lbl.gov
>     Account Name: NEWS-UNUSED
>     DONE
> (At bottom) Thunderbird now conains calendaring functionality by integrating the Lightning extension. -> "Disable"
> Quit Thunderbird, then Relaunch.
> Tools -> Account Settings.
>     Click on NEWS-UNUSED
>     Account Actions -> Remove Account -> OK
> ```
>
> 3. Find your Thunderbird "Local Folders" Directory
>
> Now you can click on "Local Folders" and then "View Settings for this
> account" to see where it is looking for local mail folders. Something
> like this:
>
> C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\syg8c7w1.default\Mail\Local
> Folders (You need to have allowed "Show hidden files, folders, and
> drives)
>
> or for Mac
>
> /Users/username/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/k994zou
> 4. Drop mbox into Local Folders
>
> Quit thunderbird. Navigate to your "Local Folders" directory in an
> explorer and drag and drop your mbox file in there. You might change
> the name to something short, like user-mbox0 or as appropriate.
> 5. Browse mbox
>
> Restart thunderbird, and you should see the mailbox in your Local
> Folders list

P.S. The versions mentioned are old but the operations in Thunderbird  do not change very much.